How to upload file to Azure OpenAI Serivce using Java?
I want to upload files to Azure OpenAI to ask question related to this file.
I don't know what model I need to use to upload? Fine-tuning or something else?
And How to upload it?
Please help me..
ex:

I upload the file SpringBoot.pdf
And then I can ask chatAi to summarize this document


There is a great example in the official Azure OpenAI Java documentation. I believe what you are looking for is the Text completions with images section which has an example for getting a response for an image, but I believe there should be a solution for documents as well.
If there is not a direct way to do so, tho, a great work around is to convert the PDFs to images and then upload them.
HOPE THIS HELPS

Thanks for your reply.
That way is similar to the thing I want, but so hard to convert the PDFs to images, because It costs a lot of resources on the server and takes time, I have a lot of clients upload big file sizes at the same time
